# L1 vs L2 norm - Circle and Diamond

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I am new to ML and recently came across the `L1` and `L2` norm.

The tutorials that I read [here](https://medium.com/@kiprono_65591/regularization-a-technique-used-to-prevent-over-fitting-886d5b361700) and [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/a-comprehensive-guide-for-linear-ridge-and-lasso-regression/) show some circle and diamond plots to explain these topics but I don't really understand the below things

[image]

a) Why are we trying to find an intersection point?

b) Does it always have to intersect?

c) I believe, the size of circle and diamond can be larger as well. Right now it's 1 (C = 1) but guess it can be C=2,3 and 4 etc as well

d) I know with linear regression gradient descent, we get the estimate `Beta` (without any constraints). So, when we use a constraint like Lasso or Ridge, why are we trying to make sure it intersects?

e) I read that this circle or diamond region is called a `feasible area`. Not sure what that means? Can help, please?

f) I read an explanation `Heuristically, for each method, we are looking for the intersection of the red ellipses and the blue region as the objective is to minimize the error function while maintaining the feasibility.` May I check what does `feasibility` mean and why does it have to intersect?

In addition, may I also know in the below graph, why does it have to intersect at the `green` contour line and not the `red` contour line

[image]

If the contour plot had been placed a little above, we could have got intersection at `green` instead of `red`?

what does `L1 Norm Isosurface` mean?

Can you guys help me?

Comment: $x_1+x_2=c$ yields a straight, downward-sloping 45° line. Based on that you can see that $|x_1|+|x_2|=c$ yields four lines that form a diamond. $x_1^2+x_2^2=c$ yields a circle (this is *the* equation for a circle). Probably not very helpful, so just posting this as a comment.

Comment: @RichardHardy - Thanks for your help. can help me understand on how do we get the circle plot shown in the question?

Comment: I understand how gradient descent works. But unable to visualize/think about how this plot came up?

Comment: @TheGreat Richard answers this in the second sentence of his comment: draw a circle with a radius $c$. From the definition of $L^2$ norm, you can immediately see that $L^2$ norm coincides with the definition of a circle.

Comment: my question is about the multiple circles' thingy and points like `2.000` , `4.00` and `8.00` etc

Comment: I uderstand those 2,4and 8 are the output (y) based on x1 and x2.. but shouldn't that be just a point...why circle is drawn?

Comment: It's a circle because multiple values $x_1, x_2$ satisfy $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 2$,  $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 4$,  $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 8$, etc., and all of those values $x_1, x_2$ form a circle together.

Comment: @Sycorax and Richard Hardy - can help me with the updated post please if you have time?